# jQuery TOS form validator (make submit button not clickable unless TOS radio button is check)

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

So I have this basic form

```
<form id="order" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <p>Your name: <span><input type="text" name="name" id="fname"></span></p>
    <p>Your e-mail: <span><input type="text" name="email" id="femail"></span></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="tos" id="ftos"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" id="fsubmit"> | <span><input type="reset" value="Clear"></span></p>
</form>
```

All I want is to make the submit button a little bit faded and un-clickable if the TOS checkbox is not checked.

if the checkbox is check, then the button will unfade and become clickable.

I am not really good on jquery but I believe it can be accomplish on Jquery.

I hope anyone could help me.

Regards,
Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is... [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/atGyy/3/)

HTML:

```
<form id="order" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <p>Your name: <span><input type="text" name="name" id="fname"></span></p>
    <p>Your e-mail: <span><input type="text" name="email" id="femail"></span></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="tos" id="ftos"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" id="fsubmit"> | <span><input type="reset" value="Clear"></span></p>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function checkTOS() {      
    var checkbox = $("#ftos").is(':checked');

    if (checkbox === true) {
       $("#fsubmit").prop("disabled",false);
    } else {
       $("#fsubmit").prop("disabled",true);
    }

}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
     checkTOS();
    $('#ftos').click( function() {
        checkTOS();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) is a good place to get you started with both HTML and JavaScript.

To answer your question, you should make the submit button un-clickable and looks differently by adding a `disabled` attribute to the element:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="fsubmit" disabled="disabled" />
```

After that, to make the button clickable after the checkbox is checked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {

        $('#ftos').change(function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                $('#fsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
            else
                $('#fsubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5dTr/1/) out! Cheers!